# State update on unmounting component - how to fix that?

Tags: reactjs

I have some problems with updating state on an unmounted component as below:

All works as expected. Modal is closed after the comment is deleted. But I'm getting a warning:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
>   This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
>   To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the
>   componentWillUnmount method

I know what causes the problem but I don't know how to fix that. Here's my data flow:

This function invokes an action responsible for deleting user posts:

```
async handleDelete() {
   const { articleID, comment, deleteComment } = this.props;
   await deleteComment({ articleID, idcomment: comment.idcomment });

   //showModal flag is set to false - hide confirmation modal after clicking 'yes' button
   this.setState({showModal: !this.state.showModal})
}
```

Action listed above 'deleteComment' looks like this:

```
export const deleteComment = data => async dispatch => {
  const { idcomment, articleID } = data;
  try {
    await axios.post(`/api/comments/${idcomment}`, {_method: 'DELETE'});
    //fetchling comments again to update a state and it looks like it causes the problem with updating a state on unmounted component because when I commented out that line, it didnt happen anymore.
    await dispatch(fetchComments(articleID)); 
  }
  catch(e) {
    throw new Error(e) }
  finally {
    dispatch(setCommentStatus(true));
    dispatch(decCommentCount());
  }
}
```

Not my question is, how to fix that? I want to close my confirmation modal after the comment is deleted from the database and the new sets of comments are already updated.

Here is how I use my modal:

```
 <Modal
   showModal={showModal}
   accept={this.handleDelete}
   denied={() => this.setState({showModal: !this.state.showModal})}
 />
```

And the last one is the modal itself:

```
return (
      !showModal
      ? ''
      : (
        <Wrapper>
          <ModalSection>
            <Header>
              <Title>Usunięcie komentarza</Title>
              <ButtonExit onClick={denied}>❌</ButtonExit>
            </Header>
            <Text>Czy jesteś pewien, że chcesz usunąć ten komentarz? <br /> Nie będziesz mógł cofnąć tej operacji.</Text>
            <Footer>
              <div>
                <Button onClick={denied}>Cofnij</Button>
                <Button warning onClick={accept}>Usuń</Button>
              </div>
            </Footer>
          </ModalSection>
        </Wrapper>
      )
    )
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the issue you are facing? Is the modal not opening or closing as expected?

Comment: All works as expected. Modal is closing after comment is deleted. But im getting a warning: `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method` and it seems like fetchComments action in deleteComment is causing the problem because without that line the warning not exist.

Comment: unrelated potential bug is using `this.setState({showModal: !this.state.showModal})` as if `state` was synchronous - it is not => don't use `this.state` inside `setState` to avoid complicated debugging.. simple `this.setState({showModal: false})` would be enough in this case

Comment: fixed that but yeah, its not the case

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it works after deleting `this.setState({showModal: !this.state.showModal})` from handleDelete function. Weird thing is after finishing deleting comment my modal is closing and I don't know HOW.. Something changing showModal value to false... Still figuring out.

**EDIT**: IM DUMB. After deleting comment I'm fetching comment list again AND that component has state of showModal set to FALSE by default so when component is rerendering the state is default which is false.................. SORRY.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are trying to modify state of Modal component after its being closed. Instead you should maintain state of comment deletion in the Parent component which renders the Modal component instead. And update the state in Parent component using a callback. This callback can be passed to Modal component as a prop and called when a delete action occurs. This should fix the issue.

Comment: But I actually do that. Modal is inside SingleComments component and in that component I modify showModal state. I'm passing thisState function from parent - SingleComponent to the child which is Modal component. So SingleComponent is resposible for state, not Modal itself.

Comment: Any ideas, hmm?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use tenary to render the modal (`!showModal ? '' : <...>`) You should pass a prop to your modal that only hides or shows the modal.
If you see some libraries they have a `show` prop or `isOpen`

e.g. [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/) [react-modal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal)

They have that prop so you don't have errors like the one you are having.

Comment: im passing a prop that is resposible for showing/closing modal. That was not the case. I explaned that in another comment is this thread. ;) Thanks anyway.

Comment: @izaakxaos `showing/closing` is different from the code you posted in your question. This  `!showModal ? '' : <...>`  is different than `display: none`

Comment: so instead of tenary i should just put different class based on showModal value?

Comment: Yes, you should only hide or show the modal, render it once and than just change the css. If you use ternary, you will remove the modal from the DOM and some of your async calls can call to a component that isn't in the DOM, causing an error